# Creating n children to a process

Tags: c, linux, loops, process, fork

As the title says, I am trying to create n children to a process. I have the following code and output. I think somewhere I allow one children to enter the loop, instead of the father, but I don't know where that happens. Or, I could think at another situation: Is the father exiting before all children are created, and the orphans are 'adopted' by another process? But, if so, shouldn't that be the init process? I'm new to linux c, forgive me if the second scenario is wrong, but I had a similar program, where the parent was exiting, and the child did not appear to be adopted by init. It might have been something else, but I'm asking in order to clarify this. I'm having these doubts because I do not see where is the 1120 process created. Many thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 5

int main()
{
    int pid[N],i=0;

    if ((pid[0]=fork())<0)
    {
        perror("fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
        if (pid[0]==0)
        {
            printf("I am 0, %d, son of %d\n",getpid(),getppid());
            exit(0);
        }
        else //father
        {
            printf("Father: I am %d\n",getpid());

            int i;
            for (i=1; i<N; i++)
            {
                if ((pid[i]=fork())<0)
                {
                    perror("fork");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                else
                    if (pid[i]==0)
                    {
                        printf("I am %d, my #no is %d, son of %d\n",i,getpid(),getppid());
                        exit(0);
                    }
                    //else                        exit(0);
            }
            exit(0);
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Father: I am 3213
I am 0, 3214, son of 3213
I am 3, my #no is 3217, son of 1120
danuts@danuts-PC:~/Desktop$ I am 2, my #no is 3216, son of 1120
I am 1, my #no is 3215, son of 1120
I am 4, my #no is 3218, son of 1120
```

Checking process 1120:

```
danuts@danuts-PC:~/Desktop$ ps -p 1120
PID TTY          TIME CMD
1120 ?        00:00:00 init
```

I was expecting it to be a daemon.. But I did not know that init could be daemon, although it is not associated with the terminal,  and have other pid than 1. Why is it having that pid? I am using Ubuntu 14.04, in multi-boot.

Comment: Did you check to see what 1120 is? -> `ps -p 1120`

Comment: Good observation. Updated my question with the check you suggested. So, it's kind of both. It's init with a pid different than 1, and the father does exit before its children.

Comment: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#session-init

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace comment // else exit(0); with line 'else wait(NULL);' it will cause parent waiting for children. Orphaned processes are adopted by 'init process'.

Comment: That works. Because, wait(NULL) expects any of the children to exit, not all of them, it could happen for a greater N, the number of process created to be less than it, couldn't it?